# Выделить лишнюю часть строки

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

В textarea выходят теги
Что можно применить в replace?

```js
var str = 'The telediva left behind Svetlana Zeynalova, Timur Soloviev and other colleagues.';
var regexp = /.+/gi; // без флага g свойство lastIndex игнорируется
regexp.lastIndex = 70; // ищем с 70-й позиции 
var obj = regexp.exec(str);
var newstr = str.replace(obj, "<span style='background:red'>" + obj + "</span>");
document.getElementById("mess").innerHTML = newstr;
document.getElementById("mess2").innerHTML = newstr;
```

```html
<textarea id="mess" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>
<div id="mess2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Оно так не работает.

```js
var str = 'The telediva left behind Svetlana Zeynalova, Timur Soloviev and other colleagues.';
var regexp = /.+/gi; // без флага g свойство lastIndex игнорируется
regexp.lastIndex = 70; // ищем с 70-й позиции 
var obj = regexp.exec(str);
var newstr = str.replace(obj, "<span style='background:red'>" + obj + "</span>");
document.getElementById("mess").innerHTML = newstr;
document.getElementById("mess2").innerHTML = newstr;
```

```css
.as-textarea {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:350px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="mess" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>
<div id="mess2" contentEditable="true" class="as-textarea"></div>
```